# Can't update the names of event attendees using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

The following has been tried using the [Microsoft Graph API Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to eliminate any third-party causes. There is an existing event in an Outlook calendar:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('WWWW')/calendars('XXXX')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"wIqdPsepnEOtI+GbtqRT1gAAElvUsQ==\"",
    "id": "YYYY",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-06-18T05:19:22.5766648Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-06-18T17:17:23.3143899Z",
    "changeKey": "wIqdPsepnEOtI+GbtqRT1gAAElvUsQ==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "ZZZZ",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Review proposal",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=YYY&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "isOnlineMeeting": false,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "recurrence": null,
    "onlineMeeting": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": ""
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T14:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T15:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "attendee@example.com",
                "address": "attendee@example.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Bob Smith",
                "address": "organizer@example.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Bob Smith",
            "address": "organizer@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

The attendee's name was not known at the time the event was created. `attendee@example.com` was given which produced an attendee whose name and email address were both `attendee@example.com`. Later, the attendee's name became known. A patch request is sent to the organizer's calendar through Microsoft Graph API to update the event with the goal of overwriting the attendee's name, but leaving the email address as is.

```
{
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
    "attendees": [{
        "status": {
            "response": "none",
            "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "attendee@example.com",
            "name": "Julie Williams"
        }
    }, {
        "status": {
            "response": "none"
        },
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "organizer@example.com",
            "name": "Bob Smith"
        }
    }],
    "createdDateTime": "2020-06-18T05:19:22.5766648Z",
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T15:00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "iCalUId": "ZZZZ",
    "id": "YYYY",
    "importance": "normal",
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-06-18T05:19:23.7881324Z",
    "location": {},
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "organizer@example.com",
            "name": "Bob Smith"
        }
    },
    "originalEndTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "originalStartTimeZone": "Eastern Standard Time",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "showAs": "busy",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T14:30:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "subject": "Review proposal",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=YYYY&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item"
}
```

The response shows that the attendee's name did not change.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('WWWW')/calendars('XXXX')/events/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"wIqdPsepnEOtI+GbtqRT1gAAElvUsQ==\"",
    "id": "YYYY",
    "createdDateTime": "2020-06-18T05:19:22.5766648Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-06-18T17:17:23.3143899Z",
    "changeKey": "wIqdPsepnEOtI+GbtqRT1gAAElvUsQ==",
    "categories": [],
    "originalStartTimeZone": "UTC",
    "originalEndTimeZone": "UTC",
    "iCalUId": "ZZZZ",
    "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
    "isReminderOn": false,
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "subject": "Review proposal",
    "bodyPreview": "",
    "importance": "normal",
    "sensitivity": "normal",
    "isAllDay": false,
    "isCancelled": false,
    "isOrganizer": true,
    "responseRequested": true,
    "seriesMasterId": null,
    "showAs": "busy",
    "type": "singleInstance",
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?itemid=YYYY&exvsurl=1&path=/calendar/item",
    "onlineMeetingUrl": null,
    "isOnlineMeeting": false,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
    "allowNewTimeProposals": true,
    "recurrence": null,
    "onlineMeeting": null,
    "responseStatus": {
        "response": "organizer",
        "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": ""
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T14:30:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-06-26T15:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "",
        "locationType": "default",
        "uniqueIdType": "unknown",
        "address": {},
        "coordinates": {}
    },
    "locations": [],
    "attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "attendee@example.com",
                "address": "attendee@example.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "none",
                "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Bob Smith",
                "address": "organizer@example.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "organizer": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "Bob Smith",
            "address": "organizer@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Should I expect the attendee's name to be updated? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I think the best option at first is to not send the attendee at all and only after you know it you update the event to add them. Yes is possible to create an event without Attendees.

Comment: @GuilhermeFlores As the question states, this is an update case. I am looking for a way to update the names of attendees after they have already been defined. Removing attendees and then adding them back with the same email address and a different name is not ideal.